# Remeshing only specific faces? (for sculpting & 3D printing)

Tags: modeling

[image]

hi,
I need to reproduce the barrel on the right in order to 3D print it and paint it (with actual brushes and paints, not digitally). I got to this point following a tutorial (iron rings not showing), but now thinking ahead about the sculpting part (I would like to sculpt the wood) I realized that in order to do so the top part would need remeshing. It is my understanding that you cannot remesh selected faces, you can only remesh the whole thing. I could start again and remesh at the very beginning but then that would mess up the procedure I followed in the tutorial, changing a few things (I'm an absolute beginner; I've tried but I came across some zero-faces errors). So, is there a way to salvage what I've already done and remesh only the top part? Or would it be easier to just forgo the sculpting part and do it with an actual knife once the part is printed? (it's very small though, 1.8 cm tall)

thank you

Comment: maybe you could make the changes with the Dyntopo option on? It will allow you to sculpt small details. It will triangulate the topology but it's not a problem for 3D printing from what I understand? Or create a grid, remove the faces only, and use it as a Knife Project tool to create additional faces on the top of the barrel?

Comment: thank you for your tips

Answer (score 0):

You can use the *Dyntopo* option to add details:

[image]

[image]

Or you can use the *Knife Project* tool in order to create more topology: Create a plane, subdivide it, delete only faces, put it above your barrel, select the barrel, switch to *Edit* mode, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Left Click</kbd> on the grid and Mesh > *Knife Project*. It will subdivide the top of your barre, and you can now sculpt some details:

[image]

[image]

Comment: thank you very much